# GTK Python display message for given time

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, pygtk

I am doing a simple GUI for Python program. In one function, I want to display a text message for a few seconds and then continue. My code for this part is:

```
self.message.set_text('This is a message')
time.sleep(3)
self.message_box.destroy()
# call another function
```

My issue is, the program firstly sleep and then displays the message and continue with destroying the message widget, instead of displaying the message for 3 seconds. I was told GTK is asynchronous and therefore it is better to use threads, however, I think for this simple program (displaying a few buttons and text messages depending on which one was clicked) it would be an overkill.

Is there any possibility how to display text for given time without threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `time.sleep()` because it blocks the gtk main loop. But you are right that threading is an overkill for your use case. You can use [`glib.timeout_add_seconds()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add_seconds). This method is actually intended to execute a function every X seconds until it returns `False`. If you return `None` it won't be called again neither. So this is a simpler approach:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(50, 20)
        label = Gtk.Label("test")
        self.add(label)
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(3, label.destroy)


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks! That function works like a charm. I think I had actually stumbled upon it, but I didn't realize I could use it like this.